# Send image from Android to Soap web Service

Tags: java, android, web-services, soap, android-ksoap2

I want to send an image from the Android device to a SOAP web service. Previously, I downloaded the image from the server from the Android device using SOAP web service, but this time I want to send the file to the server, unfortunately I encountered a problem in sending the file to the server. I tried with Base64 and String, unfortunately no data is sent to the server and it gives an error.

Error text When I send pi.setType with type String.class:

`414 request-uri too large`

Error text when I send `pi.setType` with type `Base64.class`:

> Server was unable to process request.

```
//Decode Bitmap  :
String encoded = "";
encoded =ImageUtil.convert(bitmapOut);
```

```
// Client Side :

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        
        System.out.println("@line AcntCode:" + params[1]);
        System.out.println("@line AttachFile:" + params[2]);

        SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME_FunAttachFile);

        PropertyInfo pi;


        pi = new PropertyInfo();
        pi.setName(Param_FunAttachFile_AcntCode);
        pi.setValue( params[1]);
        pi.setType(String.class);
        request.addProperty(pi);


        pi = new PropertyInfo();
        pi.setName(Param_FunAttachFile_AttachFile);
        pi.setValue(params[2]);
        pi.setType(Base64.class);
        request.addProperty(pi);

        SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER12);
        envelope.dotNet = true;

        envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);

        String path = HTTP + _ip + ASMX;

        try {

            HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(path, 10000);

            androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION_FunAttachFile, envelope);

            SoapPrimitive response = (SoapPrimitive) envelope.getResponse();

            Strresponse = response.toString();

        } catch (Exception e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
            String stackTrace = Log.getStackTraceString(e);
            System.out.println("@line e.getMessage : " + e.getMessage());
            System.out.println("@line stackTrace : " + stackTrace);

        }
        return null;
```

Bitmap to base64 conversion class :

```
public class ImageUtil {
public static Bitmap convert(String base64Str) throws IllegalArgumentException {
    byte[] decodedBytes = Base64.decode(
            base64Str.substring(base64Str.indexOf(",") + 1),
            Base64.DEFAULT
    );

    return BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(decodedBytes, 0, decodedBytes.length);
}

public static String convert(Bitmap bitmap) {
    ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, outputStream);

    return Base64.encodeToString(outputStream.toByteArray(), Base64.DEFAULT);
}
```

}

Server Side :

```
    <WebMethod(
Description:="write file")>
Public Function FunAttachFile(ByVal AcntCode As String,
                              ByVal AttachFile As String) As Boolean

    Dim log As New WriteToTextFileClass
    log.WriteTxt(" Start Request ...")

    Return True

End Function
```

Of course, I have tried other ways, unfortunately, it was not solved. If you need more documents, I will send them. I welcome any guidance.

Comment: `encoded =ImageUtil.convert(bitmapOut)` ? Is this the base64 encoding? If so then it should have been `encoded =ImageUtil.convert(raw)`.

Comment: I guess you best talk to those wo operate the server. If you operate the server yourself, please share more information on the server side as well.

Comment: Further you nowhere use String `encoded`.

Comment: Further you say you wanna send a file to the server. But we see no file. You start with a bitmap.

Comment: @blackapps Before sending, the bitmap file is converted to base64 and sent to the server through the code: pi = new PropertyInfo();
         pi.setName(Param_FunAttachFile_AttachFile);
         pi.setValue(params[2]);
         pi.setType(Base64.class);
         request.addProperty(pi);

Comment: @blackapps encoded is a variable that holds the base64 value and its value is transferred to the web service by the params[2] parameter

Comment: @queeg I added the source method that is called from the web service side. More explanation, when I call a method that has a string input parameter, it calls and returns the value without any problem. My problem starts when I want to transfer file from android phone, I get the above mentioned error.

Comment: `and its value is transferred to the web service by the params[2]` And we should have discovered that ourselves? Please write readable code to begin with. And you transfer it to an async task in that way. Not to a service.

Comment: And.... You still did not react on my first comment. You even removed code there. So now we totally have no idea how you put a file in a base64 string. And what was your problem?

Comment: By selecting the image with a small size, the request was successfully sent to the server and the problem was solved . thanks @blackapps

Comment: Solved by adding this code to send with higher volume
<system.web>
    <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="2097152" requestLengthDiskThreshold="2097152" executionTimeout="240"/>
</system.web>
<system.webServer>
    <security>
        <requestFiltering>
            <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="2147483648" />
        </requestFiltering>
    </security>
</system.webServer>